# Traducir una palabra introducida en un editText

Tags: android-studio, edittext, traducción

estoy realizando una app movil en android studio, uno de los modulos que me planteo es que el usuario por medio de un editText introduzca una palabra y pueda ver su traducción en otro idioma. Para ello pensaba en crear un archivo de recursos donde se guarden los strings de las palabras que se puede traducir y su traducción (ejemplo hola, hello). Como se ve en el código si el texto obtenido es igual a al recurso String text3 que contiene la palabra hola, se muestra en el textView la traducción de esta, si la palabra es diferente se muestra el mensaje "no se han encontrado coincidencias", sin embargo eso es solo con una palabra. ¿Como puedo hacer esto mas grande?, ¿hay alguna forma de leer todo ese archivo de recursos para buscar alguna coincidencia?. Muchas gracias.

Como nota no quiero traducir del español al ingles, en caso de que halla alguna libreria, se trata de una lengua local.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextWord;
Button btnTranslator;
TextView tvDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btnTranslator = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    tvDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btnTranslator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String traduccion = editTextWord.getText().toString();

            if (traduccion.equals(getString(R.string.text3))) {
                tvDisplay.setText(R.string.text2);
            } else {
                tvDisplay.setText(R.string.messageNotFindText);
            }
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen varias opciones, una consultando un Web Service mediante un mètodo te de la traducciòn de la palabra si existe.

Otra forma es mediante el archivo strings.xml, agrega un array con las traducciones:

```
<resources>
   
    <string-array name="words">
        <item>bones|huesos</item>
        <item>hello|hola</item>
        <item>bend|doblar</item>
        <item>become|convertise</item>
        <item>sky|cielo</item>
        <item>wizard|mago</item>
        <item>purple|purpura</item>
        <item>endeavour|esfuerzo</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Ahora itera sobre ese array y mediante .split() separa la palabra y su traducciòn y busca la coincidencia:

```
 btnTranslator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String traduccion = editTextWord.getText().toString();
        //Obtiene palabras de Strings.xml.
        String[] words = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.words);

        //Inicializa con texto que indica no se encontrò traducciòn.
        tvDisplay.setText(R.string.messageNotFindText);

        for(String s : words){
           //Busca palabra en idioma español.
           if(s.split("\\|")[1].equalsIgnoreCase(traduccion)){
               //Si existe traducciòn muestra palabra
               tvDisplay.setText(s.split("\\|")[0]);
               break; //Termina ejecuciòn
           }
        }

        /*if (traduccion.equals(getString(R.string.text3))) {
            tvDisplay.setText(R.string.text2);
        } else {
            tvDisplay.setText(R.string.messageNotFindText);
        }*/
    }
});
```